# How to merge multiple json files (metadata from website) into one json file dor EDA in python?

Tags: python, json

I am dealing with 2 folders of mixed json files and collected audios (around 400 json files), looking like this:

```
{
  "id":"c79c32e7-6665-4c5e-9458-d15930488263",
  "age":"34",
  "gender":"m",
  "healthStatus":"healthy",
  "audioFiles":[
    "1585940317337_sentence_healthy_m_34_c79c32e7-6665-4c5e-9458d15930488263.wav",
    "1585940317337_cough_healthy_m_34_c79c32e7-6665-4c5e-9458-d15930488263.wav",
    "1585940317337_breath_healthy_m_34_c79c32e7-6665-4c5e-9458d15930488263.wav"
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve `age`, `gender` and `healthStatus` and merge them into one JSON file for analysis in python.

To do this, i wrote:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json
data_folder = Path("/Users/jiani/Desktop/Voicemed/#ml/cough_classification-original_experiment/new_data/meta1")
read_files = glob.glob("data_folder/.json")

output_list = []

for f in read_files:
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        output_list.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(output_list, outfile)
```

and then I printed `output_list`, but I get an empty one. I have read some related solutions, but I still couldn't get the answer out. Could someone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use code formatting to make this readable. You don't want to make it hard for someone to answer your question

Comment: @Jnemwei where you retrieving `gender, age and healthStatus`. I didn't see any code?

Comment: @FrankC. The format has been changed. Thank you.

Comment: @komatiraju032 I want to do it after having merged all the json files

Comment: ***printed output_list, bur i get an empty one***: Your loop, `for f in read_files:` are not executed, add a`print(f)` to verify.

Comment: @Jnemwei `read_files` is empty that's why you getting empty list check once

Comment: @stovfl <_io.TextIOWrapper name='../../finalFile.json' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> this is what i get when i type print(f)

Comment: ***what i get when i type print(f)***: This could not the output of `f`, because it should show a filename instead of a `io.object`

Comment: @stovfl. it's possible that it's been overwritten cause i tried multiple method to make amends for this chunk of code.

Comment: `glob.glob("data_folder/.json")` will try to read the folder named `data_folder` in the current dir. You need to specify the full name there or use string formatting. Also probably an asterisk needed in a file pattern: `*.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import json

data_folder = "full/path/to/jsons"
files = [join(data_folder,f) for f in listdir(data_folder) if isfile(join(data_folder, f)) and f.endswith(".json")]

output_list = []
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        output_list.append({k:v for k,v in json.load(f).items() if k in ["age","gender","healthStatus"]})

with open("merged_file.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(output_list, outfile)
```

Comment: Yes, replace it with full path of the folder where all the json files you want to merge...